# Get PHP variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I cant seem to find the answer for this one. I need to grab a PHP variable and insert it into javascript.

Here is an example of what I have in the body of a PHP page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function() { 
        var info = "<?php Print($info); ?>";
        $.post($("#frm1").attr("action"), $("#frm1").serialize(), function () {
        alert(info);
        });
    });   
});
</script>

<?php
    $info="some info";
?>
<form  id="frm1" method="post" action="somepage.php">
<input name="Text1" type="text" />
<input id="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

So the problem is that the alert pops up but doesn't echo the $info string. Obviously i'm missing the right way to grab a PHP variable. Please help.

Comment: you just add value to you php var after you print it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the php variable is visible inside the inner HTML, you could do something like this to grab the variable:

HTML:

```
<span class="variable-content"><?php echo $variable; ?></span>
```

jQuery:

```
var php_variable = $(".variable-content").text();
alert(php_variable);
```

Comment: Excellent idea, thanks. I just added a hidden tag as Miko suggested below and thats it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
alert(info);
```

to:

```
alert('<?php echo "some info"; ?>');
```

Comment: Im trying to grab a PHP variable, not just echo some text. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Any the reason you can't substitute a variable is what?

Comment: With the code I showed you, you can't use the variable, It echoes nothing. Instead if I just put the string as you suggest it will work of course but that is not what I needed. The solution has been already posted, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

### Primary issue with your example code

All of the PHP executes ahead of the JS. PHP executes, then outputs Your HTML and JS to the browser where they are rendered/executed/etc.

As such, your `Print` of `$info` is executing before your declaration and definition of `$info`. You need to define it, *then* output it.

### Further issues you should consider

Once this is solved, you'll eventually run into issues with simply spewing data into the middle of JS. It is not easily maintained, and unprepared data will eventually break your JS syntax. When I have to do such a thing, I generally separate the two as much as possible:

```
<?php
    // declare and define the data
    $info = "foo";
?>

<script>
    // prepare an IIFE which takes the data as a param
    (function (info) {
        // inside this function body you can use the data as you
        // please without muddling your JS by mixing in PHP
        alert(info);
    }(
        // in the invoking parens, output encoded data
        <?= json_encode($info) ?>
    ));
<script>
```

Another benefit of this approach is that you can pass any PHP data structure to JS without changing the approach in any way. (As opposed to using inputs or element texts where you'd need to parse the JSON and keep track of which elements contain which values)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This will be useful for future coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are declaring the variable after you use it. So there is nothing in $info.

try:

```
<?php
        $info="some info";
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').click(function() { 
            var info = "<?php echo $info; ?>";
            $.post($("#frm1").attr("action"), $("#frm1").serialize(), function () {
            alert(info);
            });
        });   
    });
    </script>


    <form  id="frm1" method="post" action="somepage.php">
    <input name="Text1" type="text" />
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This would work fine if the script is on the body. But if the script is on the head and the variable is in the body it will not work. But that's just another case ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<span id="info" hidden><?php
$info="some info";
echo $info;
?></span>


<form  id="frm1" method="post">
<input name="Text1" type="text" />
<input id="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function() { 
    var info = $("#info").text();

    $.post($("#frm1").attr("action"), $("#frm1").serialize(), function () {
    alert(info);
    });

});   
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent idea, plus the hidden tag also. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use JQuery you could put the php value into a hidden input and get it from the hidden variable with JavaScript `documentGetElementById...` that way you can keep your script in the head, which seems to meet your requirements. Either the hidden span as per @Miko or:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="php_info_data" name="php_info_data" value="<?php echo $info; ?>" />
```

and in your header script which executes after the body has loaded:

```
    var info = documentGetElementById('php_info_data').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $info="some info";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function() { 
        var info = "<?php echo($info); ?>";
        alert(info);
        $.post($("#frm1").attr("action"), $("#frm1").serialize(), function () {
        alert(info);
        });
    });   
});
</script>

<form  id="frm1" method="post" action="somepage.php">
<input name="Text1" type="text" />
<input id="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var info = "<?php echo $info; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert PHP variable to JSON and then send it Javascript, becoz JSON 
is supported by all language 
Example

```
var a=<?php echo json_encode($info); ?>

alert(a);
```

or simply

```
var a=<?php echo $info; ?>

alert(a);

<?php $info=10; ?>
    <script>

        var a=<?php echo $info; ?>;
        var a1=<?php echo json_encode($info+10); ?>;
        alert(a);
        alert(a1);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
    $info="some info";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function() { 

        $.post($("#frm1").attr("action"), $("#frm1").serialize(), function () {
        alert(<?php echo $info;?>);
        });
    });   
});
</script>

<form  id="frm1" method="post" action="somepage.php">
<input name="Text1" type="text" />
<input id="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```